# How can I change the color of images in GIMP?

Tags: color, gimp

I'm creating a login form like the following. 
[image]

Now I have the color versions of the images but I don't know how to make them black and white. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a colored bitmap black and white in Gimp follow these steps:

1. Adjust *Colors > Hue-Saturation* to Saturation `-100`

   [image]
2. Make grey tones black using the *Colors > Levels* tool by dragging the black point to the right until happy (here I used `150` for black):

   [image]
3. Make the white background transparent with *Layer > Transparency > Color to Alpha* choosing (default) white as alpha color:

   [image]

Only in case there was no antialiasing from the originals we may also transfrom a colored image to black and white whithout any grey tones using the *Colors > Threshold* tool but this usually will lead to considerable aliasing artifacts.